# How do we show dynamic data in .erb file like from a json file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have a view file `index.html.erb` in my view folder and there I am showing some data in the form of Table(bootstrap table) and this is a static table so I had to write so many lines of HTML for this table.

Now, I want to a show the data in Table in a dynamic form, means I want to keep all the data in a JSON file and want to parse that data in my view file and fetch all the data by having a loop over it so I just have one block of HTML and all the table data should create through that block of code.

Or is there any other method to do this means getting the data dynamically in ruby on rails?

I did google, but everywhere I found this with ruby, but I don't know how to do this in rails, I followed this https://hackhands.com/ruby-read-json-file-hash/ in .erb file this does not work, it works only with .rb file.

Please If you have any tutorial suggestion give me the link.

Comment: Can you please share some code, your example data in json and html form ?

Comment: @ts Thanks for the reply, Bro I have written everything in question, where you did not understand.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In rails you don't do logic such as parsing JSON in a view (.erb) file.
Since you have a view, you should also have a corresponding controller.
You should do whatever parsing you need to do in the controller file, then set controller instance variables with the data that you want to display, those variable will then be available in the view (.erb) file.

Here is a very simple example from a version of the rails tutorial.

```
# controller code
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    if signed_in?
      @micropost = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
      @gravatar_url = "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{current_user.gravatar_id}?s=36"
      @markers = current_user.followed_users_map_markers
    end
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end


# partial view  code (showing how to use the variable set in the controller)
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render partial: 'shared/feed_item', collection: @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

So I think the answer to how do I parse the JSON in my view (.erb file) is you don't,  you parse it in a controller which is a pure ruby (.rb) file, then make the parsed data available to the view (.erb file) by setting controller instance variables which will also be available in the view (.erb file).

Comment: You should accept the answer if it answers your question.